# Загрузка файлов на сервер

Tags: jquery, javascript, php

Проблема такая: как только я выбираю файл/файлы, они сразу заливаются на сервер, а если
скрипт окружить `document.getElementById('feedback-form').onsubmit = function(){...}`, то не работает. В общем, файлы должны загружаться после нажатия на кнопку. Подскажите, в чем проблема и как исправить.

```
<html>
 <head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </head>
   <body>
<style>
#preloader {visibility: hidden;}
</style>
<form action=""  enctype="multipart/form-data" id="feedback-form" method="POST">
<input id="file" type="file" multiple="multiple" name="file[]" />
<div id="preloader"><img alt="loader" src="preloader.gif" /></div>
<div id="info"></div><!-- сюда будет выводится информация о заливке -->
<input type="submit" name="add" id="add" value="Загрузить" />
</form>
<script>
    $('#preloader').hide();
    $('#file').bind('change', function(){
    var data = new FormData();
var error = '';
    jQuery.each($('#file')[0].files, function(i, file) {

            if(file.name.length < 1) {              
               error = error + ' Файл имеет неправильный размер! ';            
            } //Проверка на длину имени            
            if(file.size > 3000000) {
                error = error + ' File ' + file.name + ' is to big.';
            } //Проверка размера файла
            //if(file.type != 'image/png' && file.type != 'image/jpg' && !file.type != 'image/gif' && file.type != 'image/jpeg' ) {
            //    error = error + 'File  ' + file.name + '  doesnt match png, jpg or gif';
           // } //Проверка типа файлов
        data.append('file-'+i, file);
    });

if (error != '') {$('#info').html(error);} else {

        $.ajax({
            url: 'upload.php',
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            type: 'POST',
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('#preloader').show();
            },
            success: function(data){ 
                $('#info').html(data);
                $('#preloader').hide();
            }
});
         }
    })

</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Замените

```
$('#file').bind('change', function(){
```

на

```
$('#feedback-form').submit(function(event){
event.preventDefault();
```

http://pastebin.com/s8ti59rt